# What has happened to mouse.scroll_up and other scroll commands?

Tags: autokey

This one-line script does not compile

`mouse.scroll_down()`

AttributeError:'Mouse' object has no attribute 'scroll_down'.

It is the same with `scroll_up()`, `scroll_left()` and `scroll_right()`. Adding an argument (number) makes no difference.

But these commands are shown in the [official documentation](https://autokey.github.io/api/mouse.html):

```
scroll_down(number)

Fires the mouse button 5 signal the specified number of times.

Note that the behavior of these methods are effected (and untested) by programs like imwheel.

Usage: mouse.scroll_down()

Parameters:

    number – The number of times the scroll up [sic] signal will be fired.
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is it now possible to cause a mouse scroll with autokey?

I am using autokey-gtk 0.95.10-2 under Linux Mint.

Comment: Try using the latest AutoKey version [v0.96.0](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/releases/tag/v0.96.0) from Jun 6, 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @harrymc for the version hint.

I did not know there was a later version, it's not in the Mint repository. It seems the documentation I read, and linked to, is for 0.96.0.

There's a new version of Mint due soon. I'll see if that contains the upgrade, else look at installing Autokey from github.